# How to make a database query in django by an url in javascript without making a return

Tags: python, django, background-process

i am trying change my status to 0 to 1 without intrupting the user

this function make sure that the user has read a specific portion, while clicking the read more the pargraph opens and also the status should change in the background without intrupting the user

this is my **views.py**

```
@csrf_protect
def status(self, request, pk):
    view = View.objects.get(id=pk)
    view.status = 1
    view.save()
```

my **models.py**

```
class View(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=False, default=0)
```

my **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from dashboard.views import status

urlpatterns = [  
    path('status/<int:pk>', status, name="status"),
]
```

in my template i am calling the urls using javascript

```
document.location.href ="{%url 'status' data.id %}"
```

but while calling this function **"ValueError at /status/2
The view dashboard.views.status didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."** error show up
and when i give it an httpresponse like this

```
@csrf_protect
def status(self, request, pk):
    view = View.objects.get(id=pk)
    view.status = 1
    view.save()
    return HttpResponse("")
    or
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

it redirects to an empty page with 200 written in it,the status does change but it intrupts the user

can anyone help me fix this

Comment: What you want to do is to make an async request to your view (for example using Ajax or plain Vanilla `fetch`) and return a JsonResponse which can only contain a string telling you "succeeded" for example

Comment: The ValueError is because Django needs to return a response (such as HttpResponse(status=200). The redirect is happening because your javascript is telling the browser to load the page as "document.location.href."  The solution is highlighted by @JSRB above.

Comment: Show relevant template instead.